# MS Access Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have two tables (tbl_rules and tbl_versions) with the following structure:

```
tbl_rules

rule_ID*, txtSource, txtDescription.....

tbl_versions

version_ID*, rule_ID, version.....
```

Each rule in tbl_rules has a uniq rule_ID.  tbl_versions uses the primary version_ID which ties back to tbl_rules on rule_ID, and version is just an integer that actually says what version of the rule it is (1,2,3,etc).  tbl_versions has multiple versions for each rule_ID.  My problem is I am trying to make a query that populates a form that shows all of my rules and just the LATEST version.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: `Max(Version_ID)` should work. But need to see your query first.

Comment: So generate a set of data that contains only the max Version_ID for each rule_ID from tbl_versions.  Then join that subquery it into a query with joining rules to versions; thus you have a rules w/ all versions and when joined to yoru subquery, you only get the rule with the most recent version.  (this is a common question here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @xQbert and @Ruhal for the help.  Finally got a working answer.

```
SELECT tbl_rules.*, tbl_versions.*
FROM tbl_rules INNER JOIN tbl_versions ON tbl_rules.Rule_ID = tbl_versions.Rule_ID
WHERE (((tbl_versions.version_id) In (SELECT Max(x.version_ID) AS max_version_ID
FROM tbl_versions AS x
GROUP BY x.rule_ID)))
ORDER BY tbl_rules.rule_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the latest version using `group by` first and then `JOIN` back to the rule table like

```
select r.*, xxx.highest_version
from tbl_rules r
join (
select rule_id, max(version) as highest_version
from tbl_versions
group by rule_ID ) xxx on r.rule_id = xxx.rule_id;
```

Comment: Just a minor point. w/o the join back to tbl_versions, how do you get `version` data, not the version_ID, the version value. (thus I think the main join has to include a join back to tbl_versions joining on rule_Id and the max version.

Comment: @xQbert, both table has `rule_id` which should be enough to join back

Comment: using the above how do you display `tbl_versions.version`

Comment: @xQbert, read again *trying to make a query that populates a form that shows all of my rules and just the LATEST version.*

Comment: agree.  version is a field on the table. and I think you want max(version_ID) not max(version) and then you have a join needed to get version (since you cna't just max it).  So how do you determine latest? To me it would be the one with the highest ID assuming autonumber.  the max(version) will be the one with the highest alphabetic value which may not be the latest.

Comment: @xQbert, I seriously doubt that. version is per rule ... I would suggest you to post your own answer and then if you are correct, will take off mine

Answer (score 0):

With data sets defined as:

- x is a set of data with the max(version_ID) for each rule_Id
- r is the rules
- v is the version

I  believe you would need to get the max(version_ID) per rule_ID to get the latest version from tbl_version.  I suspect `version` simply contains text about the version. If one were to get the the max of it, I doubt it would be the "latest."   We could probably get use an exists and correlated subquery to but this is one approach.

this should work because the x result set will have just one version record PER rule.  that version record will be the one with the HIGHEST version_ID.  (this assumes the highest version_Id is the latest record).  I also assume you want more than just the ID, thus the join back to the version table to get the `version` filed value.

```
SELECT R.*, v.*
FROM tbl_rules r
INNER JOIN tbl_versions V
  on r.Rule_ID = V.Rule_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT rule_id, max(version_ID) as max_version_ID
      FROM tbl_versions
      GROUP BY rule_ID ) x 
  on V.rule_id = x.rule_id
 and V.max_version_ID = x.Version_Id
```

note: other RDBMS systems support window functions and cross apply would would could eliminate a step

Comment: agreed copy/paste  typo on my part.

Comment: No worries .. most times people take it other way round .. on negative aspect ... so mentioned

Comment: No reason to be /take it negative, we're all learning and we all make mistakes.